# SPJobDefinition - base.Execute(targetInstanceId);

Tags: 2010, timer-jobs

I have a timer job that manipulates items in a list. The code for it looks something like:

```
public overrride void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
{
    //base.Execute(targetInstanceId);

    /* Code that manipulates the list here */
}
```

As you can see, the code itself isn't important.
It works fine, but what I'm intrigued about is `//base.Execute(targetInstanceId);`

What are the implications of uncommenting this out? Will it break my already working code in any way? Should I even uncomment this in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not just uncomment it but remove it if your class inherited directly from the SPJobDefinition Class and not using Child Jobs so basically no need to execute its base method.
But if you multi-inherited(whata word i make) SPJobDefinition its your decision to execute or not.

Comment: Ok, this actually makes sense now as I haven't considered child jobs before.